# Division method for Hash Values

Tags: data-structures, hash, language-agnostic

Suppose that a string of r characters is hashed into m slots by treating it as a
radix-128 number and then using the division method. The number m is easily
represented as a 32-bit computer word, but the string of r characters, treated as a
radix-128 number, takes many words. How can we apply the division method to
compute the hash value of the character string without using more than a constant
number of words of storage outside the string itself?

Comment: Please stop posting your homework questions here.  If you don't do the work yourself, you're not going to learn the subject.

Comment: homework? (blllllllllllllllllllah for SO min limit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any n-digit number in radix r:

```
number=a0*r^0+a1*r^1+a2*r^2+...+a(n-1)*r^(n-1)
```

To compute the value of the that number mod m, we do

```
(a0*r^0+a1*r^1+a2*r^2+...+a(n-1)*r^(n-1))%m
```

But, notice that

```
(a0*r^0+a1*r^1+a2*r^2+...+a(n-1)*r^(n-1))%m
   = ((a0*r^0)%m + (a1*r^1)%m+(a2*r^2)%m+...+(a(n-1)*r^(n-1))%m)%m
   = (sum over 0<=i<n: (ai*r^i)%m)%m
```

Thus, you can just iterate over one character at a time, computing the value of (ai^ri)%m and accumulate the sum.

Code (in Python):

```
def hash_code(s,radix,mod):
        pwr=1 # radix^0=1
        answer=0
        for index,character in enumerate(s):
            answer=(answer+(ord(character)*pwr)%mod)%mod
            pwr=(pwr*radix)%mod # radix^(i+1)=radix*radix^i
        return answer
```

Remember to use the % operator after every operation to avoid overflows (although this is strictly not needed in Python).

Comment: @elik1991: Python code should be fairly read. I thought the explanation would be enough to turn it into code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Horner's method/rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method).

```
y = 0
for i = (n - 1) downto 0
    y = (ai + 128y) mod m
return y
```